# setTimeout doesn't work inside setInterval

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, settimeout, setinterval, cleartimeout

I'm building a chrome addon in manifest v2. I have an interval that runs every minute. Inside it, I have a function that supposed to reload the page will reload every 3 minutes if a boolean is false. If it is true, the timer of the 3 minutes need to reset itself.

For some reason, when I'm setting the timer and logging it, it is stuck at '1'. It will move only when I will consantly set it again - which by theory should reset it but nope - it just continues.

When I call for clearTimeout, nothing happens - the timer stays the same. Even if I try to equel the timer variable into a null, it's still continues regularly.

This is the code, hope that you could help me figure this out:

```
var timerLoop = [].
var audioPlayed = false;
var timer = null;

function clearTimerLoop(){
for ( var i = 0; i < timerLoop.length; ++i ){
          clearTimeout( timerLoop[i] );
          timerLoop[i] = null; //Tried here to make it a null, no success
}

timerLoop = []; //Tried here to remove everything from the array, no success
console.log("Timer cleared");

}

function startTimer(){
        timer = window.setTimeout(refreshPage, 180000); /* reload every 3 minutes */
        timerLoop.push(timer);
        console.log("Timer created");
}

loopInterval = setInterval(function(){loopChecker();}, 60000);

function loopChecker(){
    if(audioPlayed){
        clearTimerLoop()
        timer = null;
        audioPlayed = false;
    }
         
    if(!audioPlayed && timer == null){
        startTimer();
        console.log("Refresh timer running (" + timerLoop[0] + ")");
             
    }        
    console.log(timer);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

As you can see I am resetting the timer as much as I can but nothing happens. In addition, the timer is stuck on 1 unless I set it again in every timer loopChecker() runs, and again - this should reset it but it continues.
I thought maybe every run sets a new timer so I created an array that pushes the timer each time it's created and then when I want to clear, every timer is cleared. Didn't help.

Comment: `if(!audioPlayed && timer = null)` is never fulfilled. You are assigning (`=`) instead of comparing (`==`) here. Replace it with `if(!audioPlayed && !timer)` and try again.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi yeah the other = was removed accidentally when I copied it here. Either way, it's not working. The system enters the if and starts the timer, but it gets stuck at 1.

Comment: Ah, alright. Are you also aware that your times are not what you seem to indicate they are? Not sure if they are part of the problem but your timeout is actually after 3.5 minutes, and you interval is actually every almost 12 minutes.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi yeah, it's because of so much testing and trying different options. In final it will be as I said. Edited the post, Thanks

Comment: You wrote that you're using Manifest V2. Why? It's deprecated, see [Manifest V2 support timeline](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv2-sunset/)

Comment: @ThomasMueller I need audio to work and in Manifest v3 It's not possible unless I'll open another tab and play the audio from there and then close it, which is not ideal. I'm waiting for the offscreen documents feature to release and then will migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing all of that, you can just do something like this:

```
timer = null

if (boolean == false) {
    timer = setInterval(() => {
        window.location.reload();
    }, 180000)

    ...
}
else {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = null; // stops page reloading every 3 min by deleting setInterval and its callback

    ...
}
```

Comment: I need it to work inside the first Interval. Tried what you suggested (and added in the else boolean = false it will create the timer again) and indeed when the bool is true the timer sets to null, but when the bool is false and the "new" timer is set, it continue from the last checkpoint. So if it was at '5' when the bool was true and then turned into null, when I will set it again as a timer, it will start from 5. Very strange.

Comment: Try adding clearInterval(timer) before setting timer to null. I forgot about that, apologies.

Comment: tried it. Still the same thing. Even tried pushing the timer var into an array each time I create it and then when bool is true, to go through the array and clear every interval inside it. Still somehow the timer start from where it left off.

Comment: Did you put the timer var in the global scope?

Comment: I think the issue might be the fact that you're doing the boolean check in an interval. I'm assuming you put my code inside of loopChecker, which means that the else block (containing the timer stopper) is only getting executed every 60,000 milliseconds. You could try reducing the delay to every second or some other shorter duration.

Comment: The timer var is indeed in the global scope. Tried setting the delay to  1 sec and still had the same problem. Again, the timer does turn null when it should, but when it sets back as a timer it starts from where it left off.

Comment: That's very unusual. I would need to see your updated code to know what's causing it.

Comment: Made the repository public:
https://github.com/kfirsad/MagmaNotifer

The extension is basically a search for a class and a div. If it finds them it plays audio. If it cannot find them in 3 minutes, it needs to reload the page and try again. The search only plays when the user has at least an open tab of a specific site. 

Hope you could figure this out

Comment: The timeout wouldn't start off at the same time unless it is not being cleared properly. Reloading a page will reset it as well. I still think the problem is caused by the loopChecker function since it is only being executed for a given interval and it is where you have the timer stopper.  You should probably move the portion of your code that sets the 3min timer outside the loopChecker function; have the timer start automatically when the search begins and when it finds what it is looking for, set the timer to null. Otherwise, the page reloads and the timer starts again

Comment: The timer is meant to start again though. I want it to reload the page after 3 minutes of no finding and then start again. It should reset as well when it finds what it looks for. The idea is that sometimes the site won't update so a refresh is needed so the classes that I'm looking for would appear. I did tried creating the timer in a function that is outside loopChecker() (see startTimer()) but it gave me the same result...